# Как работает анимация в JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет.

Вопрос по джейквери. Анимация.Если взять чистый джаваскрипт, то я могу взять, например, объект *div#red* "в руки" и запустить, например, через *setInterval()* изменение его стиля *CSS*, например, *left* и *right* (определяют координаты) через функцию move(). ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНО я могу взять и запустить через тот же *setInterval()* изменение стиля *CSS* объекта *div#red*, например, *font-size* (определяет размер текста) через функцию *changeFont()*. Главное в мысли то, что эти две анимации-функции ОТРАБАТЫВАЮТ ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНО - объект *div#red* движется + меняется при этом размер текста в нем. В приведенном мной примере функции *move()* и *changeFont()* как бы "шагают параллельно", а не ждут завершения друг-друга. Если бы в чистом джейквери я бы захотел выполнить некоторую функцию-анимацию 2 ПОСЛЕ того, как отработает полностью некоторая функция анимация 1, я бы в функции-анимации 1 поставил хитрое условие запуска функции-анимации 2("когда это ПОСЛЕДНИЙ запуск функции-анимации 1, то запусти функцию-анимацию 2, а она уже сама себя будет перезапускать").

Теперь возьмем джейквери. Тут есть понятие "ОЧЕРЕДЬ функций при анимации".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применительно к этому скрипту - покажется алерт, потом выполнится анимация текста, потом выполнится анимация левого марджина, потом выполнится анимация верхнего марджина, потом анимация текста, потом выполнится анимация левого марджина, потом - правого марджина. Главное в этой мысли то, что ФУНКЦИИ-ФАНИМАЦИИ ОТРАБАТЫВАЮТ ДРУГ ЗА ДРУГОМ, а не сразу все параллельно. Вся анимация в данном примере займет 6 секунд, а не 1 секунду.

**Вопрос - я хочу выполнить анимации-функции параллельно, как такое сделать с помощью средств джейквери?**

Comment: Бред скажу, но... Может задать все конечные точки в одном объекте?

Comment: И да, в `JS` нет параллельности :)

Comment: не понимаю, что значит "задать все конечные точки в одном объекте"

Comment: `.animate({fontSize: '1em', marginTop: '0', marginLeft: '0'}, 1000)` - выполняем всё за одну секунду.

Comment: .animate({fontSize: '1em', marginTop: '0', marginLeft: '0'}, 1000) - но этот скрипт не разнесешь по разным функциям, например, по move() и changeFont()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось, `animate` создаёт очередь. Глупо на мой взгляд, но не мне судить.
Главное что очередь можно выключить, установив в аргументе длительности ключ `queue` в положение `false`:

```js
function move(){
  $('#test').animate({
    marginTop: '100px'
  }, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
}

function run(){
  $('#test').animate({
    fontSize: '2em'
  }, {duration: 1000, queue: false});
}

move();
run();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Let's rock!</div>
```

P. S. Автор, пишите, пожалуйста внятнее.
Текст ВОТ ТАКИМИ БУКВАМИ только отталкивает от и так довольно сумбурного повествования.
И код не в скриншотах, пожалуйста.

Comment: я код из видеоурока выдрал). спасибо за ответ, оценил

Comment: хороший пример. мне тоже нравится рок

Comment: @Dimon, А кому не нравится? :) We will rock you, friend!